# Need help building a basic LED voltmeter

Tags: flipflop, logic-gates, counter, encoder

I have to make a LED voltmeter using basic logic gate circuits like flip flops, counters, encoders etc and show the input voltage using 7 segment displays. How do I count the input voltage. Will using counters help?

Comment: What is your excuse for not looking into basic digital voltmeter designs, finding that those mostly use **dual slope integration** to measure the input voltage and seeing that these use a counter. Now Andy was nice enough to explain it for you but in my opinion, you should have found that yourself.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75   Racist comments, even those which you think you can support factually, will almost certainly get you in excessively deep trouble extremely quickly. | One problem with "factually supportable" statements is that the 'facts' may be (and invariably are) subject to preconceptions and interpretations, **AND** the reason for some 'trends' may be outside the control of those involved. Even if such  reasons may be formed into felt-justifications for racist statements the reasons become warped and the people become the targets of generally or wholly undeserved opprobrium.

Comment: not racist just region differences of style

Comment: @FakeMoustache I did decide to use dual slope integration thanks to Andy. I didn't look into it initially because we were being taught about different types of logic gates and I didn't think my professor would give me something related to op amp integrators as a topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I count the input voltage. Will using counters help?

The "conventional" way of measuring an input voltage is to use a technique known as dual-slope-integration. Given the constraints on your usage of components I believe this might be the only way you can construct an analogue to digital converter: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/using-delta-sigma-can-be-easy-adc-part-2).

The input signal is allowed to pass into an op-amp integrator and, after a fixed length of time, the output of the integrator is forced to re-integrate (or discharge) using a fixed and accurate reference voltage as the (new) input. At this point in time, a fast counter is started.

When the integrator's output voltage passes through zero, the counter is "held" and numerically, the value it has counted to is representative of the analogue value: -

[image]

A short time later the integrator is reset (i.e. the capacitor discharged) and then the process begins again. There is a simpler method called single-slope-integration but it's more prone to measurement errors. However it is used quite a lot in converting analogue voltages to PWM: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-analog-to-digital-converter-adc-works/8/).

Comment: I would have used the circuit you provided, but can only use things like counters, flip-flops, encoders and basically everything that uses logic gates. So I was thinking the solution would be something that measures voltage like LM 3914 and then displays exactly how much it is using a 7 segment display

Comment: You cannot digitize an analogue voltage or current without using a comparator or op-amp. So if you are constrained against using these types of components then your project ends right now. An LM3914 uses comparators and op-amps so please be clear about what you are saying.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. So this will help me get the measure of the voltage? If so, then I need to convert it to binary and then put it up on the 7 segment display right?

Comment: The counter produces a binary output. You then need to make a binary to 7-segment decoder to drive the LEDs.

Comment: Note that it would be exceedingly silly to use a binary counter if you are only going to be displaying the voltage. Use a binary-coded-decimal (BCD) counter, then no conversion is required.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany good call.

Comment: @Andyaka I decided to use the dual slope adc. Can you tell me what the control logic exactly is?

Comment: Well, there are three things; integrate the signal, de-integrate to zero and reset the integrator to start again. You have a fixed integration time set by a counter and a variable de-integration time (which you count then latch). Which part of that control are you struggling with?